# Exception when trying to connect to .sdf database

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, visual-studio-2010

I have database in file `C:\Users\Pawel\Documents\DB.sdf`. How can I connect to it?

Simple code below does not work and generates exception.

Code:

```
[WebMethod]
public String TestCon()
{
    SqlConnection sql = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(
        @"Data Source=C:\Users\Pawel\Documents\DB.sdf");

    string str = "OK";

    try
    {
        sql.Open();
        sql.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        str = ex.Message;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Result:
`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)`

What am I missing? What I should do to open connection correctly?

EDIT:
`System.NotSupportedException: SQL Server Compact is not intended for ASP.NET development.`
 Great :P

Comment: Are you using SqlCompact? Looks to me you are using the normal SQL Client

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider using `System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection`:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection con = 
   new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Pawel\Documents\DB.sdf");
```

(Add a reference to System.Data.SqlServerCe, if necessary)

Also, to use it with ASP.NET, add:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("SQLServerCompactEditionUnderWebHosting", true);
```

Comment: The type or namespace name 'SqlServerCe' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Yes, you have to add a reference to System.Data.SqlServerCe assembly.

Comment: You should add a reference to System.Data.SqlServerCe to your project. (Right click on 'References' in solution explorer, 'Add reference', the rest is easy)

Comment: Read this link: http://forums.asp.net/p/1565425/3898581.aspx
It seems that guy solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you are using a SQL Compact Edition (sdf file). Have you tried using `SqlCeConnection` instead of `SqlConnection` ?

As a bonus: if you dont want to mess with connectionstrings anymore, please try [this](http://connectionstrings.com/).

Do do so, you have to add a reference to `System.Data.SqlServerCe` assembly.